# Group data by form

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, html

I have a page which displays some data from my database, how would i go about accessing this data with jQuery? By this, I mean grouping it by the row id from the database?

I was thinking about something like:

```
<input type="text" id="482983" name="reg" />
<input type="text" id="482983" name="somefield" />


<input type="text" id="482984" name="reg" />
<input type="text" id="482984" name="somefield" />
```

How could I pull that data into JSON like this:

```
{
    "482983":{"reg":"regvalue","somefield":"somefieldvalue"},
    "482984":{"reg":"regvalue","somefield":"somefieldvalue"}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: HTML id should be unique. In your html you are using more than once. Not a valid HTML. Please avoid :)

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan fair enough, perhaps i could use the name field with the id_fieldname or something like that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, IDs should be unique. Instead, let them share a class, or a name, or let them be children of the same container with a unique ID. After you've done that, you can use jQuerys .each() to form it into a json or array object.

Comment: cool, ill try putting them in a div with an id and use $("#id").each() to pull the data. Would that still work if the data was in a table and the id was assigned to a <tr>?

Comment: Yes, it would, if you make sure the selector is correct. Say, "#id input" as the selector, works even when the inputs are nested inside of <td>-tags.

Comment: great - what about for select tags, in reality I'm using 4 select's and an checkbox (input) in each row. thanks :)

Comment: Well, that depends on how you want to form it... you clearly already understand how a JSON-String works, so you figure out the logic of building that string. Should each table row eventually be one JSON-String? Do $('#id tr).each(function() { //Stuff// }); and in that stuff, read out the data. That might work wih a nested .each(), a pre-planned command that is less flexible but works for that case... Fidle around with it a bit, if you can't figure it out at all, create a jsFiddle and I'll try to help you further.